# Android Sqlite update and insert only the biggest _id

Tags: android, sqlite

I m' trying to update values only where there is  the max id like this :

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(_id) FROM test3 ", null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                db.execSQL("UPDATE test3 SET mac='" + MAC + "',mdp='" + MDP + "'");
```

But all my rows change and became the same that i choose just before and i just want the maximum to change

My database is define like this :

```
 db = openOrCreateDatabase("testDB3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test3(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,mac VARCHAR,mdp VARCHAR,obj VARCHAR);");
```

Comment: If you don't specify a **WHERE** clause, all the records will be affected by the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could run below query and update only max id :

You could run above query as single query instead of 2 queries :

```
UPDATE test3 SET mac='abc', mdp='xyz' where _id=(SELECT MAX(_id) FROM test3 )
```